# Адаптивное меню?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Подскажите пожалуйста, нужно чтобы по клику на элемент меню, открывалось sub-menu. Вложенность может быть и в 4 уровня. По-этому нужно чтобы открывалось только первое вложенное меню. Нужно чтобы это было с эффектом `slideToggle`. Получилось сделать только с `display: none`-`block`.  https://codepen.io/brezze/pen/Zxogoo

```
<ul class="menu">
  <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">2</a>
<ul class="sub-menu">
  <li>
    <a href="#">1.1</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
      <li><a href="#">2.1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">2.2</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">1.2</a></li>
</ul>
 </li>
  <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
</ul>

.sub-menu
 display: none
 margin-left: 15px

$('.menu a').click(function(){
   $('.sub-menu').slideToggle();
 });
```

Answer (score 2):

В случае с вашей структурой можно вот так. Однако она у вас очень странная.

```js
$('.menu a').click(function() {
  $(this).next('.sub-menu').slideToggle();
});
```

```css
.sub-menu {
  display: none;
  margin-left: 15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="menu">
  <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">2</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
      <li>
        <a href="#">1.1</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
          <li><a href="#">2.1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">2.2</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">1.2</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
</ul>
```